# Using the FAQ schema doesn't show a rich snippet in Google Search results

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I put the FAQ schema code on my single page (WordPress) and it doesn't display on Google result.

The code is right but I don't know why it doesn't work.

```php
<!-- FAQ schema-->
        <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_que1',true)){ ?>
        <div itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/FAQPage">
            <div itemscope="" itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h3 class="city-information_title" itemprop="name"><?php $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_que1',true);echo $post_meta; ?></h3>
                <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <p class="city-information_content" itemprop="text"><?php $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_ans1',true);echo $post_meta; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div itemscope="" itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h3 class="city-information_title" itemprop="name"><?php $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_que2',true);echo $post_meta; ?></h3>
                <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <p class="city-information_content" itemprop="text"><?php $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_ans2',true);echo $post_meta; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div itemscope="" itemprop="mainEntity" itemtype="https://schema.org/Question">
                <h3 class="city-information_title" itemprop="name"><?php $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_que3',true);echo $post_meta; ?></h3>
                <div itemscope="" itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemtype="https://schema.org/Answer">
                    <p class="city-information_content" itemprop="text"><?php $post_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dm_ans3',true);echo $post_meta; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Check if it has been crawled via the Google Search Console URL Inspection Tool. If it has it will report the FAQPage. Also, valid markup is not a guarantee that you will get rich results.

Comment: Google is notoriously slow, very very slow. What are you expecting and how long has it been? Cheers!!

Comment: my blog indexed and submitted but just published almost 7 days

Comment: 7 days is not enough time for Google to process all that it needs to. It may be weeks or months before Google picks up any mark-up and take advantage of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google guidelines [make it clear](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies) that rich snippets are not guaranteed, even if the code is correct:

> Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results, even if your page is marked up correctly

Those guidelines offer several reasons why a rich snippet may not be shown, many of which relate to the content itself.

I recommend checking through those and making any necessary adjustments. Also, if you don't already have one, set up a [Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) account so you will be notified of any manual actions that may have been applied.

Answer (score 1):

Folks have already mentioned possible reasons for the rich result not showing up in Google.

> One thing which I personally noticed is that **FAQ Rich Results** show
>   up only for results showing on the first page. Though there is no such
>   mention I have come across in Google Guidelines.

Since "Google does not guarantee that your structured data will show up in search results."

**All you can do is, implement Structure Data correctly and keep your fingers crossed.**

Implementation of FAQPage Schema in WordPress is quite straight-forward. It involves three major steps:

1. Adding FAQPage Structured Data (generated using in-page markup
   called JSON-LD, recommended by Google) to the webpage. You can do
   **this with or without using a WordPress Plugin**.
2. Validating the webpage for FAQ Schema Correctness using Google's [Rich Results Test
   Tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results).
3. Submitting the webpage for fresh Indexing by crawling the page via Google Search Console.

Comment: Please do not promote your site in your answers

Answer (score -1):

The FAQ schema is only supposed to show in the search results when more than one website in top positions are using it.

Comment: Do you have a reference to share to verify this?   This sounds plausible, but it having a reference would make this much more authorative.

Comment: It's just an observation.